# Difference between command run ->'protractor protractor.conf.js' and 'npm run e2e '

Tags: angularjs, npm, protractor

I want to know the exact difference between this two command when we run those using angular Cli project terminal-

1. protractor protractor.conf.js' --> Basically it launches baseurl provided in protractor.conf.js instead of using localhost
2. 'npm run e2e ' --> Basically it does not launches baseurl provided in protractor.conf.js instead it launches localhost

I am confused while running e2e test -like which command to use and if dont want use #command 1 how it will launch basurl

thanks for your help

Comment: Please show your `package.json` in your question

Comment: Please move the content of package.json in question, don't add by comment. And delete that two comments.

Answer (score 0):

the `e2e` in `npm run e2e` comes from the `e2e` in`scripts` in your package.json.

[image]

So `npm run e2e` actually executed command `ng e2e` which comes from Angular CLI,

`ng e2e` generally will do two things:

1. Compile and start your app at local
2. execute `protractor protractor.conf.js` to the app started at Step 1,
   It will ignore the `baseUrl` in protractor.conf.js, only respect the url
   where app started at Step 1

If you want `ng e2e` respect the `baseUrl` in protractor conf file, you need to start app before execute `ng e2e` and append option `--no-serve`:

`ng e2e --no-serve`